# Hyperledger Fabric: Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory: the supplied identity is not valid

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we see this error when trying to start a peer and are wondering how can we fix it?

```
2019-03-21 00:17:33.657 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/mydir: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error verify that the msp directory has a folder `cacerts` inside it which contains the certificate of the authority you have used to obtain the cert under `signcerts` and `admincerts` folder. If you are using an intermediate CA then you should also have an `intermediatecerts` folder under the msp dir. Example of correctly setup msp:

```
root@1741bbd6e1ee:/home# tree peer05-jnj
peer05-jnj
|-- admincerts
|   `-- cert.pem
|-- cacerts
|   `-- ica-jnj-7054.pem
|-- intermediatecerts
|   `-- ica-jnj-7054.pem
|-- keystore
|   `-- 75446a991f94558a0821a8cf8258746171359580f907bae88aa5f937e197bbc5_sk
|-- signcerts
|   `-- cert.pem
|-- tlscacerts
|   `-- tls-ica-jnj-7054.pem
|-- tlsintermediatecerts
|   `-- tls-ica-jnj-7054.pem
`-- user
```

The `admincerts` is mandatory when starting a peer. If there is no admincert, you get below error:

```
2019-03-21 18:00:10.985 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/peer03-jnj: could not load a valid admin certificate from directory /home/peer03-jnj/admincerts: stat /home/peer03-jnj/admincerts: no such file or directory
```